# @subcomponent.factory method is missing parameters for required modules or subcomponents

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, android-mvp

> I am injecting Presenter to **BookDashboard**(Activity) and **BookDashboardPresenter** class require an **MvpView** `interface` in it's constructor .

When i run

**AppComponent**

```
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidInjectionModule::class,
        ActivityBuilder::class
    ]
)
@Singleton
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        fun addContext(@BindsInstance context: Context): Builder
        fun addBookEngine(@BindsInstance bookEngineModule: BookEngineModule) :Builder
        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

**ActivityBuilder.kt**

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilder {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {BookEngineModule.class})
    public abstract BookDashboard bindBookDashboard();
}
```

**BookEngineModule.kt**

```
@Module
class BookEngineModule(val mvpView: BookDashboardContract.MvpView){

    @Provides
    fun providePresenter():BookDashboardContract.Presenter{
        return BookDashboardPresenter(mvpView)
    }
}
```

**BookDashboardContract**

```
interface BookDashboardContract {

  interface MvpView{
    fun displayBooks()
    fun showProgress()
    fun hideProgress()
  }

  interface Presenter{
    fun fetchedBooks()
  }
}
```

**BookDashboardPresenter.kt**

```
class BookDashboardPresenter @Inject constructor(val viewContract:BookDashboardContract.MvpView) : BookDashboardContract.Presenter{

    val bookInteractor = BookInteractor(this)

    override fun fetchedBooks() {
        bookInteractor.fetchDataFromServer()
        viewContract.displayBooks()
    }
}
```

**BookDashboard -> Activity**

```
class BookDashboard : DaggerAppCompatActivity(),BookDashboardContract.MvpView{

    @Inject
    lateinit var presenter: BookDashboardContract.Presenter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        DaggerAppComponent.builder().addContext(this).
            addBookEngine(BookEngineModule(this)).build()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ///presenter.fetchedBooks()

    }

    override fun displayBooks() {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Books Displayed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    override fun showProgress() {}
    override fun hideProgress() {}
}
```

But when I build the project I am having below error

```
ActivityBuilder_BindBookDashboard.java:24: error: @Subcomponent.Factory method is missing parameters for required modules or subcomponents: [quiz.mania.trivia.mcq.question.di.BookEngineModule]
    interface Factory extends AndroidInjector.Factory<BookDashboard> {}
```

**DaggerClass**

```
@Module(subcomponents = ActivityBuilder_BindBookDashboard.BookDashboardSubcomponent.class)
public abstract class ActivityBuilder_BindBookDashboard {
  private ActivityBuilder_BindBookDashboard() {}

  @Binds
  @IntoMap
  @ClassKey(BookDashboard.class)
  abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<?> bindAndroidInjectorFactory(
      BookDashboardSubcomponent.Factory builder);

  @Subcomponent(modules = BookEngineModule.class)
  public interface BookDashboardSubcomponent extends AndroidInjector<BookDashboard> {
    @Subcomponent.Factory
    interface Factory extends AndroidInjector.Factory<BookDashboard> {}
  }
}
```

above class can't resolve BookEngineModule and BookDashboard

What am i missing ?

Comment: Dagger can't find provider for `BookDashboardContract.MvpView` to construct `BookDashboardPresenter` - you need to resolve that

Comment: see BookEngineModule

Comment: I saw it, it's passed through constructor of module. But where `dagger` can find it? Dagger doesn't know how to get that dependency

Comment: I have added this code in BookEngineModule @Provides
    fun providesMvpView(bookDashboard: BookDashboard):BookDashboardContract.MvpView{
        return bookDashboard
    }
but still not working